# Stored procedure is returning output with different order on multiple SQL databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure (called `sp1`) which is doing a join between two tables.

Schema for tables is like:

```
Table1 (id, country, name, ccy)
Table2 (sId, price)
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
SELECT
    RTRIM(id) as id,
    country
FROM
    dbo.Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.sId
```

On one database, I am getting the following result

```
MNKD US     UnitedStates
928502811   UnitedStates
```

But on another database, I am getting the result with different order:

```
928502811   UnitedStates
MNKD US     UnitedStates
```

The only significant difference is table one consist of many columns while table 2 has only two columns.

Can someone help me to figure out the reason and how to fix it to get the consistent result? Thanks

Comment: without an order by , all bets are off...that's why it's called 'ORDER BY'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL tables and results sets are *unordered* by default.  The only exception is when a query explicitly has an `order by`.  Without an `order by`, the same query on the same database on the same data can return values in a different order when called multiple times.

If you want the results in a particular order, then add an `order by`:

```
select trim(id) as id, country
from dbo.Table1 left outer join
     dbo.Table2
     on Table1.Id = Table2.sId
order by id;
```

Comment: When i am using "where clause" with in stored procedure, it always gives in same order. so is it fine or only order by guarantees the correct order? Thanks

Comment: @mohituprim: ***ONLY*** using an explicit `ORDER BY` guarantees any order - anything else is just a lucky coincidence

Answer (score 1):

Rows in the database don't have an order.

If you want to order your result in a certain way you will need to use the ORDER BY clause so for example:

```
SELECT
RTRIM(id) as id,
country
from dbo.Table1 
left outer join dbo.Table2 on Table1.Id = Table2.sId
ORDER BY id
```